# I renamed my photos last year including extension too, Now I am not able to recall a name of photos,How can I find my photos on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, photos, file-search

I renamed my photos last year including extension too, Now I am not able to recall a name of photos or directory where it was stored, How can I find my photos on windows 7? Is there any tool to do this or I need to write a code for this, I renamed my photos in bulk.

I renamed all pictures with same name at once eg. Pic name was xyz.jpg,pqn.jpg... etc then I selected all file and rename with one name let say done.txt (assuming extension changed to .TXT) then all files are with number like done[1].txt,done[2].txt

Comment: What was the new extension?

Comment: Not recalling that as well

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/245313/find-missing-image-on-drive-without-knowing-the-name-or-extension

Comment: Were all these photo files created at the same time (for example copied from camera)?

Comment: You could list all your folders with the command line, maybe if you see the folder name your memory comes back: dir /s /b /p /ad /a c:\

Comment: @harrymc yes those pictures are captured in mobile phone & I remember a date on which it got captured

Comment: @Ricardo I tried that but no luck.. I renamed all pictures with same name at once eg. Pic name was xyz.jpg,pqn.jpg... etc then I selected all file and rename with one name let say done.txt (assuming extension changed to .TXT) then all files are with number like done[1].txt,done[2].txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell to search your whole PC for the files that were modified 1 year or before more ago:

```
$drv=gdr -psp fileSystem|select -eXp root
$drv|%{
dir $_ -rec|?{($_.extension-in@(".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".gif"))-and($_.lastwritetime-gt((get-date).adddays(-365))}|%{
[pscustomobject]@{'Filepath'=$_.fullname}}}|ogv -titl "Photos"
```

Comment: But there are many files which got modify last year

Comment: Maybe look for files >1 MB that got modified last year?

Comment: @kish it will just look for .png,.gif and .jpegs

Comment: @wasif but I renamed extension too.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free
[Everything by voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/)
to search your disk.

After installing Everything, start it and give it the time needed to index
the entire disk. After it finishes, searches will be lightning-fast.

For example, you could search for : `datemodified:2019 size:large`.
"large" means files whose size is between 1 MB and 16 MB.

When the result is displayed, click the column of "Date Modified" twice to
sort the files by descending order.
Then look for many files modified on the same day.

Note that renaming a file does not change its modification date, so the date
to search is when the photos were created, not when the rename was done.

For more information, see
[Everything : Searching](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/searching/).

Comment: The date of these photos on the computer could be the one you remember, and in that case they would be easy to find. However, depending on the transfer method, it could also be the date you transferred them to the computer.

Comment: yes I know everything but filter you suggested might help me to ease. Will check.